# Agrupar data de diferentes tablas html y enviarlas con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario donde genero una tabla segun el identificador y dentro de esas tablas genero filas para agregar un sub-idenficiador.
Este es mi html estatico (lo dinamico ya lo tengo)

```html
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>identificador 1 (ejemplo Talla S)<input type="text" value="talla S"></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Sub identificador</th>
<th>Unidades</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input value="Color Rojo"></td><td><input value="5"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="Color Verde"></td><td><input value="25"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="Color Azul"></td><td><input value="15"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>



<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>identificador 2 (ejemplo Talla M)<input type="text" value="talla S"></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Sub identificador</th>
<th>Unidades</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input value="Color Rojo"></td><td><input value="5"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="Color Verde"></td><td><input value="25"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="Color Azul"></td><td><input value="15"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>identificador 3 (ejemplo Talla L)<input type="text" value="talla S"></th></tr>
<tr>
<th>Sub identificador</th>
<th>Unidades</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td><input value="Color Rojo"></td><td><input value="5"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="Color Verde"></td><td><input value="25"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input value="Color Azul"></td><td><input value="15"></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Mi problema esta en como agrupar la informacion de todas estas tablas y enviarlo a mi php para almacenarlo en mi base de datos:

Detalles:

1. Cabe recalcar que tengo 2 input mas aparte de las tablas tales como nombre_del_producto y categoria y obviamente necesito esa informacion tambien.
2. E pensado en recorrer las tablas y almacenar la informacion en un json o array y eso enviarlo a php

De antemano gracias por la ayuda, no tengo ningun codigo que haya intentado porque no se por donde empezar para solucionar mi problema

Comment: Deberías poner el código que genera la tabla dinámicamente, porque ahí es donde se ponen los identificadores para después poder recorrerlas sin problemas. Hazlo y podremos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: Ninguno de esos _input_ tiene atributo _name_, ¿cómo piensas acceder a ellos?

Comment: @Triby supongo que con un input:nth-child(...)  ??

Comment: @DigiSoul las tablas se repiten, es decir el html de la tabla que ves alli es el mismo que uso en mi .append() ;

Comment: Si las tablas se repiten, lo ideal es poner los identificadores en la función que genera las tablas. Si no es posible, pon el código completo, incluyendo los dos inputs que faltan y te explicaré como hacerlo tal y como lo tienes, asumo que cuando haces el append() es uno para cada tabla y lo que estás añadiendo es una variable con el código html de la tabla y además que antes de hacer el append() sabes cuantas tablas has añadido ya.